# How does "unlocking a sub-domain" work for the "Kobold Faith" feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, cleric, domains, kobold

I know that normally clerics must choose two domains that their deity supports, but I found something interesting concerning the [Kobold Faith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/kobold-faith-kobold) feat. The big staple of this feat is the "unlocking" of a sub-domain on top of the regular domain. So, considering that there could be copies of this feat for other races, AND you can make up your own god, I want to know if this means:

A) The Sub-Domain replaces the Main Domain

B) The Sub-Domain becomes the second Domain for the character

or C) The Sub-Domain is added on top of the regular 2 Domains

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### An unlocked subdomain is one that a character can now choose and isn't added to the normal number of domains a character possesses

The racial trait [Kobold Faith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/kobold-faith-kobold) says

> You gain a +2 trait bonus on Diplomacy checks when dealing with other kobolds. Additionally, if your deity grants the [Artifice](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/artifice-domain), [Earth](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain), or [Trickery](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/trickery-domain) domain, then your kobold faith unlocks a corresponding subdomain: [Trap](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/artifice-domain/trap-subdomain), [Radiation](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain/radiation-subdomain), or [Ambush](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/trickery-domain/ambush-subdomain).

But the term *unlock* isn't a technical term. However, in its introduction to the Kobold Faith trait, [*Kobolds of Golarion*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601255128) (2013) explains

> Even kobolds who worship the same deities as surface dwellers put a kobold spin on their religious practices. This results in some rare subdomains which are accessible only to kobold followers of that faith. The following race trait grants access to the subdomains detailed below.

So here *unlock* means *able to be picked*. That's because [Domains](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains) on Subdomains says that

> **A cleric who chooses a subdomain must have access to both the domain and its subdomain from her deity.** If a cleric selects a subdomain, she cannot select its Associated Domain as her other domain choice (in effect, the subdomain replaces its Associated Domain). Subdomains are treated as equivalent to their Associated Domain for any effect or prerequisite based on domains. If a subdomain has two Associated Domains, the cleric can only select the subdomain for one of her domains.

Emphasis mine. As all three of the [Trap](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/artifice-domain/trap-subdomain), [Radiation](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain/radiation-subdomain), and [Ambush](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/trickery-domain/ambush-subdomain) subdomains were introduced in *Kobolds of Golarion*, there were only a few ways to allow existing gods to grant those subdomains, and designers appear to have chosen the trait Kobold Faith rather than, for example, issuing errata or updates for all deities that should've been granting those subdomains all along, in essense saying, "You want a kobold with the radiation subdomain *that* badly? Take a trait."

### The short version

Taking the trait [Kobold Faith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/kobold-faith-kobold) allows a kobold that is **already** allowed to pick the domain [Artifice](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/artifice-domain), [Earth](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain), or [Trickery](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/trickery-domain) to pick **instead** the subdomain [Trap](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/artifice-domain/trap-subdomain), [Radiation](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/earth-domain/radiation-subdomain), or [Ambush](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/trickery-domain/ambush-subdomain), respectively.